# How to make an extension Paid and Upload on Magento Connect

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

We have developed an extension and need to upload it on Magento Connect. This would be our first extension on marketplace.

Could anyone guide me on the following queries

1. How to upload an extension on Magento Connect ?
2. Does it require a special merchant account to upload any extension ?
3. How can I upload a paid extension on Magento Connect ?
4. Do I need to redirect user to my website in order to complete the
   extension purchase ?
5. How to define warranty, support, and contact information ?

Please help and guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How to upload an extension on Magento Connect ?
     For that you need to follow the [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/creating_magento_connect_extension_package)
2. Does it require a special merchant account to upload any extension ?
     No there is no special merchant account required.
3. How can I upload a paid extension on Magento Connect ?
     when you upload your extension then it will ask for price you have to enter price.
4. Do I need to redirect user to my website in order to complete the extension purchase ?
   In Landing Page field  you have to enter your URL .
5. How to define warranty, support, and contact information
   this can you manage on your Purchase Site.

For Creating Package you have to take care of Magento Standards. for that you can [Download PDF From Hear.](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf)

Let me know if you want any more information.

It will look like as below Image
[image]

Comment: How do I create a package file and upload the same on magento connect ?

Comment: for that you have to follow the PDF link

Comment: @KeyulShah : hi friend, I didn't see any upload button in `version` tab. How can I upload my file ?

Comment: @hi I have update my answer. It will look like this please change the browser.

Comment: @KeyulShah : Please take a look on this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33062/cant-find-upload-button-in-magento-connect-to-upload-my-extension?noredirect=1#comment44656_33062

Comment: Please change the browser and check it again